# drag and sortable only work first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing drag and sort function. i have 2 Draggable area. you can take a look at URL

https://study-navin10sharma.c9.io/

1.Just take city as example and drop into active reason it work and then take again city out of Active reason still everything fine. But again if you try to add city in Active reason then city block will be invisible.

With each drag i perform sort operation dynamically.

```
$(function() {
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  helper: 'clone',
  containment:"document",
  revert:"true",
  tolerance:"pointer"
   });
 });

 $("#sortable2").sortable({
  stop: function ( event, div){
  data = $(this).sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'data-id' });
  //Here we perform our ajax request
 },
 receive: function (event, ul) {
  ul.item.remove();
 }
 });

 //WITH EACH DRAG it connect with sort
 $("#sortable1>div").draggable({
   connectToSortable: "#sortable2",
   helper: "clone",
   revert: "invalid",
   axis :"y"
   });

$("#sortable2>div").draggable({
connectToSortable: "#sortable2",
helper: "clone",
revert: "invalid"
});

//HERE SOME HTML REFERENCE  
  <div id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable"> <span class="ui-sortable-handle">  ACTIVE</span></div> 

  <div id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable"> 
    // Here i have list of the element that i want to Drag
   </div>
```

One more things currently once i drag the item sorting trigger but this not a good way may be once element drop then sorting need to be start.
Please help me to sort out this problem. if there anything else you want let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: i have updated the post please check...